# Pandas Merge/Join/Concat 2 DFs Based on Multiple Similar Columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

I need to create a final dataframe that combines 2 dfs that have matching row values in sequence of another common column (months). I'm combining current year (2022) data for months 1-6 for one df and combining data for current year (2022) for months 7-12. Here is my df1:

```
id  r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  month   name    year
1   4   4   4   4   4   1   nets    2021
2   20  20  20  20  20  2   nets    2021
3   8   8   8   8   8   3   nets    2021
4   5   5   5   5   5   4   nets    2021
5   3   3   3   3   3   5   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  6   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  7   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  8   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  9   nets    2021
6   1   1   1   1   1   10  nets    2021
6   11  11  11  11  11  11  nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  12  nets    2021
7   5   5   5   5   5   1   nets    2022
8   9   9   9   9   9   2   nets    2022
9   12  12  12  12  12  3   nets    2022
10  21  21  21  21  21  4   nets    2022
11  2   2   2   2   2   5   nets    2022
12  17  17  17  17  17  6   nets    2022
13  3   3   3   3   3   1   warriors    2021
14  7   7   7   7   7   2   warriors    2021
15  3   3   3   3   3   3   warriors    2021
16  4   4   4   4   4   4   warriors    2021
17  1   1   1   1   1   5   warriors    2021
18  4   4   4   4   4   6   warriors    2021
19  1   1   1   1   1   7   warriors    2021
20  7   7   7   7   7   8   warriors    2021
21  18  18  18  18  18  9   warriors    2021
22  12  12  12  12  12  10  warriors    2021
23  7   7   7   7   7   11  warriors    2021
24  4   4   4   4   4   12  warriors    2021
25  11  11  11  11  11  1   warriors    2022
26  6   6   6   6   6   2   warriors    2022
27  2   2   2   2   2   3   warriors    2022
28  17  17  17  17  17  4   warriors    2022
29  24  24  24  24  24  5   warriors    2022
30  22  22  22  22  22  6   warriors    2022
```

And, here is the df2 that I need to combine to df1 in the month sequence and based on the "name' and "year" columns that match in both dfs. df2:

```
id  month   name       1    2   3   4   5   year
1   7       nets      10    25  14  4   22  2022
2   8       nets       5    8   6   24  18  2022
3   9       nets      18    8   8   14  16  2022
4   10      nets      19    11  13  8   9   2022
5   11      nets      16    25  3   9   6   2022
6   12      nets      17    11  18  3   24  2022
7   7       warriors  15    24  11  2   25  2022
8   8       warriors   1    7   18  9   17  2022
9   9       warriors  11    11  8   18  20  2022
10  10      warriors  16    20  3   24  2   2022
11  11      warriors  10    24  6   4   19  2022
12  12      warriors   8    16  12  19  22  2022
```

And, i need the result to look like this in a new df3 where the new months data where month = 7-12 of the current year (2022) have been added or combined for each name (nets, warriors).

```
idx r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  month   name    year
1   4   4   4   4   4   1   nets    2021
2   20  20  20  20  20  2   nets    2021
3   8   8   8   8   8   3   nets    2021
4   5   5   5   5   5   4   nets    2021
5   3   3   3   3   3   5   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  6   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  7   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  8   nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  9   nets    2021
6   1   1   1   1   1   10  nets    2021
6   11  11  11  11  11  11  nets    2021
6   19  19  19  19  19  12  nets    2021
7   5   5   5   5   5   1   nets    2022
8   9   9   9   9   9   2   nets    2022
9   12  12  12  12  12  3   nets    2022
10  21  21  21  21  21  4   nets    2022
11  2   2   2   2   2   5   nets    2022
12  17  17  17  17  17  6   nets    2022
13  10  25  14  4   22  7   nets    2022
14  5   8   6   24  18  8   nets    2022
15  18  8   8   14  16  9   nets    2022
16  19  11  13  8   9   10  nets    2022
17  16  25  3   9   6   11  nets    2022
18  17  11  18  3   24  12  nets    2022
19  3   3   3   3   3   1   warriors    2021
20  7   7   7   7   7   2   warriors    2021
21  3   3   3   3   3   3   warriors    2021
22  4   4   4   4   4   4   warriors    2021
23  1   1   1   1   1   5   warriors    2021
24  4   4   4   4   4   6   warriors    2021
25  1   1   1   1   1   7   warriors    2021
26  7   7   7   7   7   8   warriors    2021
27  18  18  18  18  18  9   warriors    2021
28  12  12  12  12  12  10  warriors    2021
29  7   7   7   7   7   11  warriors    2021
30  4   4   4   4   4   12  warriors    2021
31  11  11  11  11  11  1   warriors    2022
32  6   6   6   6   6   2   warriors    2022
33  2   2   2   2   2   3   warriors    2022
34  17  17  17  17  17  4   warriors    2022
35  24  24  24  24  24  5   warriors    2022
36  22  22  22  22  22  6   warriors    2022
37  15  24  11  2   25  7   warriors    2022
38  1   7   18  9   17  8   warriors    2022
39  11  11  8   18  20  9   warriors    2022
40  16  20  3   24  2   10  warriors    2022
41  10  24  6   4   19  11  warriors    2022
42  8   16  12  19  22  12  warriors    2022
```

thank you for you help,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to rename your columns so that they are the same in both dataframes, i.e. there is index alignment, and then use `concat` on `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename({str(n):f"r{n}" for n in range(1,6,1)},axis=1)]).sort_values(by=['name','year'])
```

prints:

```
    id  r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  month      name  year
0    1   4   4   4   4   4      1      nets  2021
1    2  20  20  20  20  20      2      nets  2021
2    3   8   8   8   8   8      3      nets  2021
3    4   5   5   5   5   5      4      nets  2021
4    5   3   3   3   3   3      5      nets  2021
5    6  19  19  19  19  19      6      nets  2021
6    6  19  19  19  19  19      7      nets  2021
7    6  19  19  19  19  19      8      nets  2021
8    6  19  19  19  19  19      9      nets  2021
9    6   1   1   1   1   1     10      nets  2021
10   6  11  11  11  11  11     11      nets  2021
11   6  19  19  19  19  19     12      nets  2021
12   7   5   5   5   5   5      1      nets  2022
13   8   9   9   9   9   9      2      nets  2022
14   9  12  12  12  12  12      3      nets  2022
15  10  21  21  21  21  21      4      nets  2022
16  11   2   2   2   2   2      5      nets  2022
17  12  17  17  17  17  17      6      nets  2022
0    1  10  25  14   4  22      7      nets  2022
1    2   5   8   6  24  18      8      nets  2022
2    3  18   8   8  14  16      9      nets  2022
3    4  19  11  13   8   9     10      nets  2022
4    5  16  25   3   9   6     11      nets  2022
5    6  17  11  18   3  24     12      nets  2022
18  13   3   3   3   3   3      1  warriors  2021
19  14   7   7   7   7   7      2  warriors  2021
20  15   3   3   3   3   3      3  warriors  2021
21  16   4   4   4   4   4      4  warriors  2021
22  17   1   1   1   1   1      5  warriors  2021
23  18   4   4   4   4   4      6  warriors  2021
24  19   1   1   1   1   1      7  warriors  2021
25  20   7   7   7   7   7      8  warriors  2021
26  21  18  18  18  18  18      9  warriors  2021
27  22  12  12  12  12  12     10  warriors  2021
28  23   7   7   7   7   7     11  warriors  2021
29  24   4   4   4   4   4     12  warriors  2021
30  25  11  11  11  11  11      1  warriors  2022
31  26   6   6   6   6   6      2  warriors  2022
32  27   2   2   2   2   2      3  warriors  2022
33  28  17  17  17  17  17      4  warriors  2022
34  29  24  24  24  24  24      5  warriors  2022
35  30  22  22  22  22  22      6  warriors  2022
6    7  15  24  11   2  25      7  warriors  2022
7    8   1   7  18   9  17      8  warriors  2022
8    9  11  11   8  18  20      9  warriors  2022
9   10  16  20   3  24   2     10  warriors  2022
10  11  10  24   6   4  19     11  warriors  2022
11  12   8  16  12  19  22     12  warriors  2022
```

Comment: sorry, but i get the index error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects